# video id returned by youtubeanalytics.report.query not found by youtube.videos.list

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I get metrics returned by youtubeanalytics.report.query for ~90 videos but when I try to use the video id with youtube.videos.list api, I don't get a hit on all of them.  Anyone know why?

Comment: Can you give an example of some of the video IDs you got that didn't return a result  when you called youtube.videos.list?

Comment: XpPc2Xbvz0k
XQaLlovphXI

Comment: interestingly, when I use the API explorer, they both come back with data, but in my python app where I use both youtube_analytics.report.query and youtube.video.list, only the report.query returns data.

Comment: Make sure that you're using the latest version of the Python client library and double check that you have the Youtube Data API enabled.

Comment: I updated Python client libraries, and yes the Youtube Data API is enabled.  When I re-ran the test, the 2 aforementioned video_ids got data from both API's but there are still others that did not, seems like "random" occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the request was "failing silently", after I implemented error handling I was able to see the failure, my fix was to pause the app slightly and re-try, seems to have done the trick, I no longer experience the issue.